# Spring SimpleFormController, Showing error msg on the formView

Tags: spring, validation, exception

I'm using Spring SimpleFormController to handle a form submission with validation. I expect a case where an exception will occur inside my "onSubmit" method. In such a case, i want the user to see the original formView with all the data filled in plus the error message from the exception.

I've checked around, i see people recommend a class from Spring like *ExceptionMapper which it can forward user to a page with friendly error message.

So please share me on how to make this happen?

dara kok

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SimpleFormController` and `onSubmit`, you are probably not using Spring annotations and related features.  You could do something like the following in your controller. In your client-side, you can use the contents of `error` object to display errors, along with the form.  Note that `onSubmit()` and `showForm()` are deprecated in spring 3.0.

```
@Override
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
        response, Object command,   BindException errors) throws Exception {
        // Do your processing
        if (somethingWentWrong) {
            errors.reject("error.server.error");
            return showForm(request, response, errors);
        } else {
           return new ModelAndView(getSuccessView());
        }
}
```